# Landsat: Searching for and downloading cloud-free images for a small area

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, earth-explorer

My study area is quite small (10 x 4 km). I would like to get all cloud free (say < 10% cloud cover) landsat images over that area, for a given time period (say, over 10 years). I cannot use the 10% cloud cover cutoff in EarthExplorer because it is for the whole scene. That is, I might miss a lot of images where it was mostly cloudy over the scene but was cloud free over my study area. So is there a good way to search for and download all suitable landsat images? I have my study area demarcated as a shapefile.

Comment: What area are you looking at ? Because it depends on the area where there is a cloud free or not... It is hard to find one that is cloud free...

Comment: You could potentially use Google Earth Engine and sort the least cloudy image of the series of images over your region and download that one?

Comment: My area is in Finland, where it is quite cloudy. But I see "gaps" in many scenes, hence the question. And thanks Vijay for the suggestion of Google Earth Engine. I have not tried it out yet, but will give a detailed look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try if you get stuck with the Google Earth Engine...

Here are the potential Landsat for download free...

https://libra.developmentseed.org/

https://landsatlook.usgs.gov/viewer.html

https://research.csc.fi/open-gis-data

Finish National Satellite Centre :

Looks like doesn't have Landsat but has Sentinel there..

http://nsdc.fmi.fi/index.php

Comment: This is possible in Google earth engine :)